# How to start powershell with a window title?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have a batch file that allows me to go to particular folder based on my input.

```
d:
cd d:\test\bits
@ECHO off
cls
:start
ECHO.
ECHO 1. Perl
ECHO 2. Python
set choice=
set /p choice=type in number to go to appropriate code folder:
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if '%choice%'=='1' goto pl
if '%choice%'=='2' goto py
ECHO "%choice%" is not valid, try again
ECHO.
goto start
:pl
cd code\pl
goto end
:py
cd code\py
goto end
:end
start "bits"
```

At the end of execution, a command prompt window with the title "bits" opens up and is in the specified directory corresponding to the input choice. This is all good. But I want to have the same thing done with Powershell.

If, instead of `start "bits"`, I put, `start powershell`, in the last line, I can get Powershell console to open. By doing this, I have two issues.

1. Powershell console is still in `d:\test\bits` folder and not in the one I intended it to go.
2. I cannot get the title to be `bits`

How do I get the functionality I want with Powershell?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From what I expected and what I was able to reproduce with your script, the current directory is set to the intended one (`d:\test\bits\code\pl` if I enter 1)

For the title part, you can do the following:

```
start powershell -NoExit -command "$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'bits'"
```

Comment: I am able to set the title now. However, for me, the current directory is not being set to the intended one. After cmd is reaching the last line, which is invoking Powershell, it seems to have started off fresh with no memory of the commands in the original batch file. I am not sure how you are doing it.

Comment: @steeluser - I tried with the exact script that you have posted and with the last line changes to the powershell one I have posted. It is working exactly as expected. I am not sure what is different with you system. What OS btw?

Comment: My mistake. It took me a while to realize that the prompt function in my profile.ps1 is set to open `d:\test\bits`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to your powershell profile.ps1 you can get the window title to show the current running script and if you are just opening a window with no script then 'pwsh' will be displayed.

Will be systematic with no need to add a line on top of each script. The other answers
combined with `$MyInvocation.MyCommand` seem to give the name of the profile.ps1 instead when running a script from the context menu.

This can also be tweaked to change the result.

```
[console]::title = Split-Path -Leaf ([Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[-1]).Replace('pwsh.dll','pwsh')
```

Works on both PS 5 and 7 . For ver. 5 replace `pwsh.dll` by `powershell.exe`