# Set window title when running "start powershell" in powershell not working?

Tags: powershell

The following command works in `CMD` ([How to start powershell with a window title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891110/how-to-start-powershell-with-a-window-title)).

```
start powershell -NoExit -command "$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'bits'"
```

But it doesn't work in Powershell.

```
PS C:\> start powershell -noexit -command "$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'test'; read-host"
Start-Process : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'noexit'.
At line:1 char:18
+ start powershell -noexit -command "$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'test ...
+                  ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

The following command can open a new powershell window.

```
start powershell "$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'test'; read-host"
```

However, the new window shows the following error message and the title is not set.

```
System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHost.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle : The term
'System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHost.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHost.UI.RawUI.Wind ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.Manageme...wUI.WindowTitle:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: `start powershell '-NoExit -command "$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = ''bits''"'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Bacon Bits' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57235309/45375) explains that `start` in `cmd.exe` means something different than in PowerShell.

Use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) as follows to get the desired result; note that `powershell` implicitly binds to parameter `-FilePath`, whereas the `,`-separated arguments starting with `-NoExit` bind implicitly to the `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`) parameter, which accepts an *array* of *strings*:

```
# In PowerShell, `start` is an alias for `Start-Process`
start powershell '-NoExit', '-command', "`$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'bits'"
```

In paticular, `-`-prefixed *pass-through* arguments must be *quoted* so that they're not mistaken for `Start-Process`'s own parameters.

Also note the `` ` `` preceding the `$` in `$Host`, which prevents *up-front* interpolation of `$Host` by the *calling* PowerShell instance.

You could also use `'$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = ''bits'''`, a single-quoted *literal* string with *embedded* single quotes escaped as `''`.

---

**Important**:

While passing arguments as an *array* to `-ArgumentList` is *conceptually* the best approach, it is unfortunately ill-advised due to a **long-standing bug in `Start-Process`**, still present as of this writing (v7.1)  - see [GitHub issue #5576](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576).

**For now, using a *single* string comprising *all* arguments, enclosed in *embedded* `"..."` quoting as necessary, is the only generally robust approach**. As discussed in the linked GitHub issue, an `-ArgumentArray` parameter that supports robust array-based argument passing may be introduced in the future.

In the case at hand this means the following, as suggested by [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) in a comment on the question:

```
Start-Process powershell '-NoExit -command "$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = ''bits''"'
```

- Note the *single*-quoting_ (`'...'`) of the overall argument-list string, which then necessitates escaping the *embedded* single quotes - those that PowerShell should see as part of the command - as `''`.

Comment: This was the second time (first was with regex) I've been bit by the first round of variable expansion. The backtick is essential if you want to use some first round expansion of variables but let others be handled by the new session.

Answer (score 1):

In Command Prompt, `start` is [the `start` internal command](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html). In Windows Powershell, `start` is an alias for [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6), which does something similar but isn't identical.

Try running this:

```
powershell -NoExit -command "`$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'bits'"
```

Comment: It doesn't pop up a new window. I want a new window to be popped up. (I actually need to run multiple windows in parallel.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, while avoiding the dollar sign.  The double quotes have to be on the outside, so that bits stays quoted.

```
start powershell "-noexit (get-variable host).value.ui.rawui.windowtitle = 'bits'"
```

You can always avoid these quoting issues putting the command in a file.

```
start powershell '-noexit .\window.ps1'
```

Comment: Or, even shorter: `(Get-Host)`.

Comment: The default-verb logic is alluring, but obscure and fragile, as your example shows. Additionally, it performs poorly and isn't fully integrated - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3987

Answer (score 0):

start powershell with the command option for setting the window title did not work for me. Maybe because I want to open another powershell with a ps1 file. so in the other ps1 file I added the first line as below,

`(Get-Host).ui.RawUI.WindowTitle='TEST TEST'`

and it worked like a charm....

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to your powershell profile.ps1 you can get the window title to show the current running script and if you are just opening a window with no script then 'pwsh' will be displayed.

Will be systematic with no need to add a line on top of each script. The other answers
combined with `$MyInvocation.MyCommand` seem to give the name of the profile.ps1 instead when running a script from the context menu.

This can also be tweaked to change the result.

```
[console]::title = Split-Path -Leaf ([Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[-1]).Replace('pwsh.dll','pwsh')
```

Works on both PS 5 and 7 . For ver. 5 replace `pwsh.dll` by `powershell.exe`